# GeckoFX 22 by pass self sign cert

Tags: geckofx

i am implementing a GeckoFX Browser using c#.
i need to navigate to a secure self sign cert. but GeckoFX throw me this error.

**The certificate is not trusted because the issuer certificate is not trusted.
The certificate is only valid for FG200B3913601572
(Error code: sec_error_untrusted_issuer)**

How do i bypass the Check?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could try this code, but it requires the latest version of Geckofx (build from source):

```
browser.NSSError += (s,e) => {
    CertOverrideService.RememberRecentBadCert(e.Uri);
    Uri refUrl = browser.Url;
    browser.Navigate(e.Uri.AbsoluteUri, refUrl != null ? refUrl.AbsoluteUri : null);
    e.Handled = true;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

In GeckoFx 60 *RememberRecentBadCert* is now depraced so you have to use *RememberValidityOverride*

```
browser.NSSError += (s, e) =>
{
    if (e.Message.Contains("Certificate"))//Peer's Certificate issuer is not recognized.
    {
        CertOverrideService.GetService().RememberValidityOverride(e.Uri, e.Certificate, CertOverride.Mismatch | CertOverride.Time | CertOverride.Untrusted, false);
        if (!e.Uri.AbsoluteUri.Contains(".js") && !e.Uri.AbsoluteUri.Contains(".css")) browser.Navigate(e.Uri.AbsoluteUri);
        e.Handled = true;//otherwise shows error
    }
};
```

Reference: https://bitbucket.org/geckofx/geckofx-60.0/src/default/Geckofx-Core/Services/CertOverrideService.cs

With handling cert errors my browser started to work almost normally but still those cert errors were causing unexpected errors. Thats why I added cert I wanted to use to Windows root certificates. But it still didnt work. Finally I have found out that GeckoFX by default doesnt import stored Windows certificates  and it has to be enabled by these preferences:

```
GeckoPreferences.User["security.enterprise_roots.enabled"] = true;
GeckoPreferences.User["security.enterprise_roots.auto-enabled"] = true;
```

This 2 prefs did the job and finally I didnt get ANY "Untrusted certificate" errors. Heuréka !

Answer (score 1):

```
geckoWebBrowser1.NSSError += geckoWebBrowser1_NSSError;

void geckoWebBrowser1_NSSError(object sender, Gecko.Events.GeckoNSSErrorEventArgs e)
            {
                if (e.Message.Contains("Certificate"))
                {
                    Gecko.CertOverrideService.GetService().RememberRecentBadCert(e.Uri, e.SSLStatus);
                    geckoWebBrowser1.Navigate(e.Uri.AbsoluteUri);
                    e.Handled = true;
                }

            }
```

Try it in gecko 33

Answer (score 0):

The code above does not work on version 29.0.2. There is a bug which caused the CertOverrideService.RememberRecentBadCert call to error out.

After upgrading to 29.0.11 it worked perfectly.

Here is the VB.NET code.

```
Sub IgnoreSSLError(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As Gecko.Events.GeckoNSSErrorEventArgs) Handles WebBrowserRehab.NSSError
        CertOverrideService.RememberRecentBadCert(e.Uri)
        WebBrowserRehab.Navigate(e.Uri.AbsoluteUri)
        e.Handled = True
End Sub
```

Comment: I know it has been awhile, just wanted to update, if anyone is wanting this in GeckoFx 45, although RememberRecentBadCert is now obsolete and one should probably use RememberValidityOverride

`Function Browser_Error(ByVal sender As Object, e As Gecko.Events.GeckoNSSErrorEventArgs)

    If e.Message.Contains("certificate") Then
        Gecko.CertOverrideService.GetService().RememberRecentBadCert(e.Uri, e.SSLStatus)
            browser.Navigate(e.Uri.AbsoluteUri)
            e.Handled = True
        End If
    End Function`

Comment: Should have probably just made it a separate answer. My b.