# GeckoFx use Certificate

Tags: c#, geckofx

Im using GeckoFx 45.

In Firefox, I click on a button, it asks for a certificate. I choose it and it goes on.
In GeckoFx, when I click on the button, it returns the error **SSL peer was unable to negotiate an acceptable set of security parameters.**

I don´t know how to make GeckoFx ask for the certificate or how do I set one.

Tryed to send in header, but it didn´t worked, returning the same error.

```
X509Certificate2 certificate;
var headers = Gecko.IO.MimeInputStream.Create();
headers.AddHeader("X-Client-Cert",certificate.GetRawCertDataString());
wb.Navigate(e.Uri.AbsoluteUri, GeckoLoadFlags.None, "", null, headers);
//wb is the GeckoWebBrowser
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I think you are using an invalid self-signed cert or the root cert is missing.. Here are some related suggestions that might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19238425/geckofx-22-by-pass-self-sign-cert and here is some technical context: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/728969#answer-3967

Comment: I tryed the suggestions, but it didnt worked.
In Firefox, it asks for a certificate. I choose one and it works perfectly.
In GeckoFx it don´t asks for one and i don´t know how to set one

Comment: I tried to check how one could install a cert manually on the GeckoFx BitBucket repo but it looks like the project does not exist anymore. https://bitbucket.org/geckofx/geckofx Its probably best moving on to alternatives. :/